# "range of function" vs "target of function"?

Tags: functions

Page 14 of [Fundamentals of Computer Graphics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568814690) states that if we have a function like this:

[image]

...the set that comes before the arrow is called the *domain* of the function, and **the set on the right-hand side is called the *target***.

...The point f(a) is called the *image* of *a*, and the image of a set *A* (a subset of the domain) is the subset of the target that contains the images of all points in *A*. **The image of the whole domain is called the *range* of the function.**

Then what exactly is the difference between the *range* of a function and the *target* of a function?

Comment: See [Domain, Co-Domain & Range of a Function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59432/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that the range may not be the entire target. Consider the function $f(x)=x^2$ from $\{-1,0,1\}$ to $\{-1,0,1\}$; its domain and target are both $\{-1,0,1\}$, but its range is only $\{0,1\}$.

By the way, the more usual name for the target is *codomain*. The range is sometimes called the *image*.

Comment: Do you mean that the *target* is arbitrarily defined and can be anything?

Comment: @Pacerier: Anything that includes the actual range, yes.

Comment: Hmm, then isn't the *range* a more useful term since the *target* could be well.. *anything*. What's the point of *target* anyway, when we already have *range*?

Comment: @Pacerier: They’re useful in different ways, though the value of the target only becomes fully apparent at a more advanced level. For a simple example, though, consider whether a function $f$ with domain $D$ is *surjective* (or *onto*). You can’t tell if you don’t know the target: the range doesn’t give you enough information. And there are times when it’s important to know whether a function is surjective.

Comment: It would be fascinating to know what the downvoter imagines is wrong.