# Creating a composite function that is injective with an injective and a non-injective part

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Find an example of functions $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ such that $f$
and $g\circ f$ are both injective, but $g$ is not injective.

So If I understand this correctly,

1. Need a function $f$ that is injective and that will also make $g$ injective when plugged in during $g\circ f$.
2. Need a function $g$ that is not injective on its own
3. The range of $f$ must be a subset of the domain of $g$

I tried thinking along the lines of using variations of $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$ but all those leave my composite function as non injective

I've also been using $x\in\Bbb R$ so as to keep the range of $f$ and domain of $g$ the same.

Any suggestions of where to go with this? Thank you

Edit:
Thank you everyone the answers were very helpful in understanding the problem and concepts better

Comment: `The range of f must be the domain of g` No. Range of $f$ needs only be a *subset* of the domain of $g$.

Comment: ah so the range of $f$ could be just natural numbers or something like that while the domain of $g$ is the real numbers?

Comment: Yes. See more at [Domain, Co-Domain & Range of a Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59432/domain-co-domain-range-of-a-function) for example.

Comment: It's worth noting that if "the range of $f$ is the domain of $g$" then $g$ being non-injective is enough to make the composite function non-injective. This is easy to see, take $a,b\in \text{Dom}(g)$ such that $g(a)=g(b)$. They are witnesses to the fact that $g$ is not injective. Since range of $f$ is the domain of $g$ there exist, $x,y$ such that $f(x)=a$ and $f(y)=b$ than $(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))=g(a)=g(b)=g(f(y))=(g\circ f)(y)$ and so $g\circ f$ is not injective.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**.  Let's take $g:{\Bbb R}\to{\Bbb R}$ with $g(x)=x^2$ as you suggested - a good, simple, well-known function which is not one-to-one.  Suppose we want $f:{\Bbb R}\to{\Bbb R}$ also.

To say $g\circ f$ is one-to-one means: if you know the value of $g(f(x))$ then you know the value of $x$ - that is, know it for sure, with only one possibility.  So, suppose the value of $g(f(x))$ is given.  We have
$$g(f(x))=(f(x))^2\ ;$$
a good way to proceed from here would be [1] find the value of $f(x)$, then [2] find the value of $x$.  Step [2] is easy as $f$ is supposed to be one-to-one.  The problem is that step [1] would usually give you two values of $f(x)$.

But now suppose, for example, that $f(x)$ is always positive.  Then step [1] gives a definite value of $f(x)$ and all is OK.

So - can you think of a (well known) one-to-one function $f:{\Bbb R}\to{\Bbb R}$ for which $f(x)$ is always a positive number?

Hope this doesn't sound too long-winded but I am hoping to illustrate *how you can think about* this kind of problem.

Comment: Good answer. And now I shall spoil it: Most people will think of the function $f:x\mapsto e^x$, and then the composition becomes $x\mapsto (e^x)^2 = e^{2x}$ which is a familiar injective function.

Comment: Additionally, I like the fact that we take $A=B=C=\mathbb{R}$ here. Some other examples may make you think that such examples occur only because you pick one of the sets "artificially" small (when in fact there is a natural continuation to all of $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen what do you mean by $A=B=C=\mathbb{R}$? The trick is that the range of $e^x$ is $(0,\infty)$ if it were $\mathbb{R}$ it wouldn't work.

Comment: @DRF The sets from the question, where $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$. I know $f$ cannot be surjective, because then the failure of $g$ to be injective would lead to the composition $g\circ f$ failing to be injective as well. I think David already explained that in his answer. But if you compare to Parcly Taxel's answer, where $f(x)=x$, one could ask why this $f$ is restricted to the domain $A = \left[ 0,\infty \right)$. We could also just take $A=\{ 0\}$ and $B=\{ 0,1\}$, you know. I know every example is essentially the same. I just think it is more elegant to have $A=B=C=\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 6):

Take $f:[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ with $f(x)=x$ and $g:\Bbb R\to[0,\infty)$ with $g(x)=|x|$. Then $f$ is injective and $g$ is not, while $g\circ f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ is the identity function and is therefore injective.

Comment: So in this case $g$(x) isn't injective because $R$ can't map fully onto [0,∞) right

Comment: @mathminutemaid Actual reason: $g(-1)=g(1)=1$.

Comment: R has plenty of injective maps to $[0, \infty)$, it's just that g is injective on the subset which f characterizes and not all of R

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my comment and downvote again. Sorry for the rubbish.

Answer (score 2):

$g:B\to C$ being non-injective means that there are distinct $b,b'\in B$ with $g(b)=g(b')$. All you need is to ensure that the image of $f$ never contains both values $b$ and $b'$ at the same time (maybe neither).

**Example**.

Choose $g(x)=x^2$, then the injectivity violating pairs are $(x,-x)$ for $x>0$. Just make sure that if $f(x)=y$, then there is no $x'$ with $f(x')=-y$, e.g. choose

$$f(x)=e^x$$

which is injective and will only assume positive values. Note that here $A=C=\Bbb R$ and $B=(0,\infty)$.