# Is the set $\{\langle \varnothing, a \rangle ,\langle \{ \varnothing \}, b \rangle \}$ considered as function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The set defined as
$$F=\{\langle\varnothing,a \rangle, \langle \{\varnothing\},b\rangle\}$$
a function?

Comment: Is $\langle a,b\rangle$ notation for ordered pair?

Comment: It may also depend on [what definition of function you are using](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59432/domain-co-domain-range-of-a-function). In some definitions, you need to specify two sets in addition to a collection of ordered pairs.

Comment: Yes, $\langle a, b \rangle$ is ordered set. I think it is equivalent to $\{ a, \{a,b\}\}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're using the "functions-as-sets-of-ordered-pairs" approach, then **yes**, it is: its domain is $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$, it sends $\emptyset$ to $a$, and it sends $\{\emptyset\}$ to $b$. Crucially $\emptyset\not=\{\emptyset\}$, so there's no inconsistency here.

(The other standard approach to functions views a function as a set of ordered pairs *together with* a specific mention of domain and codomain. Of course the domain is determined by the set of ordered pairs (at least, if we don't allow partial functions), but the codomain is not, so this is a genuinely different approach. If we take this stance then what you've written **is not** a function.)

*EDIT: note that the parenthetical remark is exactly the point Arturo Magidin makes in his comment above.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes:  it is a function that maps $F: \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\} \to \{a,b\}$.

As $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ are two distinct and different mathematical objects and each element of the domain, $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$, is mapped to precisely one element of the codomain, $\{a,b\}$ and not element of $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ is mapped to more than one element of $\{a,b\}$, $F$ satisfies every definition of a function.

(Edit:  Noah and Artruro make the valid point that the the domain can be inferred to be $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ but the codomain is unsepecified.  The codomain $\supset \{a,b\}$ and if your texts requires a codomain *must* be specified then this technically is not a function but that's fairly picky.  For must practical purposes I believe most would consider this a function.)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is a function, and if you adopt the usual definition that $0 = \varnothing$, $1 = \{ \varnothing \}$, then this function maps from $\{ 0, 1 \}$ to real (or complex) numbers, and its explicit form is: $F(0) = a, F(1) = b$.

Comment: This is a good short answer, but says  too much.There is no need to identify the domain as the set $\{0,1\}$ nor the codomain as the real or complex numbers.

Comment: The domain is $\{a,b\}$ not the reals.

Comment: the codomain $\supset \{a,b\}$.  Could be just about any set so long as it contains $a$ and $b$ which could be *any* type of object.  No reason to assume they are numbers.  No reason at all.